# How to cast 'FIRDataSnapshot' to NSString & NSDict

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm getting the error of could not cast value of type 'FIRDataSnapshot' to 'NSString'. Neither the retrieve names or retrieve quantities/manfacturers is working. Both give the same casting error essentially.

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

    // Retrieve Names

    ref.child("rawMaterials").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            self.rawMaterialNames.append(child as! String)
        }
    })
    //Retrieve Quantities and Manfacturers

    for name in rawMaterialNames {
        ref.child("rawMaterials/\(name)").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                for i in data {
                    let quantity = data["quantity"] as! String
                    let manafacturer = data["manafacturer"] as! String
                    self.rawMaterialManafacturers.append(manafacturer)
                    self.rawMaterialQuantities.append(quantity)
                  //self.rawMaterialQuantities.append(data!["quantity"] as! String)
                  //self.rawMaterialManafacturers.append(data!["manafacturer"] as! String)
                }
            }
        })
```

Edit: Since, no one has been able to help, maybe I'm not providing enough. My firebase realtime database tree looks like this

App Name

-contracts

---ContractTest

-rawMaterials

---Optional("Paint")

--------manafacturer: "Optional(\"Paint Company A\")"

--------quantity: "Optional(\"120\")"

---Optional("Lead")

Comment: try as ? NSDictionary

Comment: that doesn't work @TheeBen

Comment: Hmm, sorry it's been awhile I havn't coded in swift and can't see what's the problem. I'll let you know if I find out but I doubt you can cast Snapshot to NSString, it has to a dictionary or map of some sort. Perhaps I don't understand your question.As far as I remember, "Any" was always causing problem for me. If you can make it more clear in your code, where is the problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a step to be able to cast to String:

```
ref.child("rawMaterials").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let nameSnapshotValue = child.value as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let name = nameSnapshotValue["name"] as! String //or whatever the dictionary key is...
        self.rawMaterialNames.append(name)
    }
})
```